# Fetching data from JSON in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

i am new at react native. I fetch data on Firebase but i want to fetch it JSON file. My JSON file like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51lDy.png)

how can i change firebase url to my php json url?
PLEASE HELP ME
This is my code:

```
return async (dispatch, getState) => {
// any async code you want!
// const userId = getState().auth.userId;
try {
  const response = await fetch(
    'https://shopapp-f9964.firebaseio.com/products.json'
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
  }

  const resData = await response.json();
  const loadedProducts = [];

  for (const key in resData) {
    console.log(resData[key].description);

    loadedProducts.push(
      new Product(
        0,
        0,
        resData[key].product_image,
        resData[key].description,
        resData[key].price,
      )
    );

  }

  dispatch({
    type: SET_PRODUCTS,
    products: loadedProducts,
    //userProducts: loadedProducts.filter(prod => prod.ownerId === userId)
  });
} catch (err) {
  // send to custom analytics server
  throw err;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to get from API (or Json response).

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
});
```

Here is the official docs, it really helps for you to understand data from JSON file

https://reactnative.dev/docs/network

here is the working example on **Snack**

https://snack.expo.io/@asad_4561/b21f6d?session_id=snack-session-EGg1r5WPo&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=g11cgnoglm&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=Fetch%20Example&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true